# How to count group wise in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a table with name of the person and where does he go for shopping. I want to find the count of maximum occurrences of every individual with the name of the supermarket.

For example in the below file if Alan goes to Costco for the maximum number of times to shop then output should have his name and name of the store along with the count of how many times he went there. I need to find this count for all the individuals in the file given below.

```
Alan Costco
Ryan Walmart
Jim Costco
Steve WholeFoods
Ryan WholeFoods
Jim Walmart
Alan Costco
Ryan Walmart
Jim Costco
Steve WholeFoods
Ryan WholeFoods
Jim Walmart
Alan Costco
Ryan Walmart
Jim Costco
Steve WholeFoods
Ryan WholeFoods
Jim Walmart
Alan Costco
Ryan Walmart
Jim Costco
Steve WholeFoods
Ryan WholeFoods
Jim Walmart
Alan Costco
Ryan Walmart
Jim Costco
Steve WholeFoods
Ryan WholeFoods
Jim Walmart
Alan Walmart
Jim WholeFoods
Ryan Costco
Steve Walmart
```

Answer (score 1):

See here for explanation on [COUNT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#COUNT)

```
A = LOAD 'file_path/test36.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (a1 : chararray, a2 : chararray);
B = GROUP A BY (a1,a2);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group,COUNT(A.a2) AS Total;
DUMP C;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
shopdata = LOAD 'path_of_filename' USING PigStorage(',') as   (name:bytearray,mall:bytearray);

groupdata = group shopdata by (name,mall); 

reqdata = foreach groupdata generate group.name as customer,group.mall as shopping_mall,COUNT(shopdata.mall);

dump reqdata;
```